# We stopped hearing from agent Hosted Agent. Verify the agent machine is running and has a healthy network connection

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-virtual-machine

all- i use azure pipelines for test execution from last 2 days and i got results when i connected to the azure VM,
as part of the scripts the result will be stored in surefire reports but in drop box there is no result,

please help me resolve this.

4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.qsgsoft</groupId>
<artifactId>ExpenseManagement</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>ExpenseManagement</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.apple</groupId>
        <artifactId>AppleJavaExtensions</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.commons.io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.supercsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>super-csv</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jxls</groupId>
        <artifactId>jxls-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jxls</groupId>
        <artifactId>jxls-reader</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.13</version>
    </dependency>    
</dependencies>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>acceptanceSuitePartA</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>AcceptanceSuite1.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>acceptanceSuitePartB</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>AcceptanceSuite2.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>acceptanceSuite</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>testngAcceptance.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>scenariosSuite</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>scenarios.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>stressSuite</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <urlForExecution>${url_For_Execution}</urlForExecution>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>parallelTest.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    
    <profile>
        <id>stressSuiteNew</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <urlForExecution>${url_For_Execution}</urlForExecution>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>stressTest.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>regressionSuite</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>regression.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

</profiles>
```

This the pom.xml
there are two machines for acceptance suite 1 and 2 - in acceptance suite1 am getting this error
Every day azure pipeline will automatically triggers and when we connect to azure VM through RDP file there in drop box sure fire report will get store and also screenshots. i did latest code check in in azure VM from there am getting this error
FYI- we use "tmp" folder in c drive to store screenshots there we will get screenshots

Comment: You've provided **no** detail that can be used to help you troubleshoot. What steps have *you* taken to troubleshoot this? Please provide as much background and context on the nature of your configuration as possible.

Comment: @DanielMann-- let me know if you need any more information

Answer (score 1):

i got this error because my execution time was more than 6 hours,
i will add one link here so if any one encountered with this same error you can go through this link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#capabilities-and-limitations

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).